# Compiled console app quits immediately when importing ConfigParser (Python 2.7.12)

Tags: python-2.7, configparser

I am very new to Python and am trying to append some functionality to an existing Python program. I want to read values from a config INI file like this:

```
[Admin]
AD1 = 1
AD2 = 2
RSW = 3
```

When I execute the following code from IDLE, it works as ist should (I already was able to read in values from the file, but deleted this part for a shorter code snippet):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ConfigParser

# buildin python libs
from time import sleep
import sys

def main():
    print("Test")
    sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But the compiled exe quits before printing and waiting 2 seconds. If I comment out the import of ConfigParser, exe runs fine.

This is how I compile into exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    zipfile = None,
    console=['Test.py'],
    )
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there maybe another way to read in a configuration in an easy way, if ConfigParser for some reason doesnt work in a compiled exe?

Thanks in advance for your help!